# Convex analysis of robust counterpart reformulation

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

In the paper "Deriving robust counterparts of nonlinear uncertain inequalities", a theorem states that the vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$  with $U=\left\{a=a^{0}+A \zeta \mid \zeta \in Z \subset \mathbb{R}^{L}\right\}$ satisfies the robust counterpart
$$(R C) \quad f(a, x) \leq 0, \quad \forall a \in U$$
if and only if $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ satisfy the inequality  $\left(a^{0}\right)^{T} v+\delta^{*}\left(A^{T} v \mid Z\right)-f_{*}(v, x) \leq 0$.

The derivation is conducted by using the indicator function and Fenchel duality,
$$\begin{aligned} F(x): &=\max _{a \in U} f(a, x) \\ &=\max _{a \in \mathbb{R}^{m}}\{f(a, x)-\delta(a \mid U)\} \\ &=\min _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}}\left\{\delta^{*}(v \mid U)-f_{*}(v, x)\right\} \end{aligned},$$ which makes sense to me.

My question is: by writing (RC) to $F(x) \leq 0$, the resulted inequality seems to be $\min _{v \in \mathbb{R}^{m}} \left(a^{0}\right)^{T} v+\delta^{*}\left(A^{T} v \mid Z\right)-f_{*}(v, x) \leq 0$. Why could the min operator in the theorem be ignored?

Any hint would be appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you find any $\nu$ satisfying that inequality, then the same inequality with minimum operator is trivially satisfied.

If $\exists \hat{\nu}\in dom(\nu)$ s.t. $(a^0)^\intercal + \delta^*(A^\intercal \hat{\nu} \rvert Z)-f_{*}(\hat{\nu},x)\leq 0$, then $\min\limits_{\nu}(a^0)^\intercal + \delta^*(A^\intercal \nu \rvert Z)-f_{*}(\nu,x)\leq 0 $ is always satisfied.

It means that with that $\hat{\nu}$, we can guarantee that original robust counterpart is $\textit{robust feasible}$.

So you do not have to solve inner minimization first(which leads to complicated bi-level program), but rather just solve one (large) optimization problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kim!

Comment: Welcome:) i also use  Frc on my current research. Hope this might help yours too